# BlackBerry GridLayoutManager column always display field in the center

Tags: blackberry

I just create a simple blackberry application which use GridLayoutManager for manage my field in the screen, below the snippet:

```
GridFieldManager gfm = new GridFieldManager(2, 3, 0);
gfm.add(new LabelField("AGUS ZULVANI"));
gfm.add(new LabelField("B"));
gfm.add(new LabelField("C"));
gfm.add(new LabelField("D"));
gfm.add(new LabelField("E"));
gfm.add(new LabelField("F"));

gfm.setColumnPadding(20);
gfm.setColumnProperty(0, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, 100);

add(gfm);
```

Label "D" display in center align..
how I can make it to left align?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know off the top of my head if GridFieldManager respects the style bits, but the first thing I would try is: `new LabelField("D", Field.FIELD_LEFT)`